# Java Regex matching url with/without http or with/without www

Tags: java, regex

could you please someone tell me how to match these types of url in string?

For example:

```
example.com
www.example.com
http://example.com
https://www.example.com
example.com/exam1/exam.php
example.com/exam
...
```

Actually, I need to detect all forms of URL you can see for example on Twitter in plain text.

I have tried to find some regex by google but I couldn't find something which fits all the types in Java.

**UPDATE:** Maybe I wasn't too precise - I need find all these types of url in plain text and replace them by some token. For example: status.replaceAll(yourRegex, "*URL*");

Thank you!

Comment: you mean you just need to match every one with example.com?

Comment: Don't use a regex for that; use the [`URI` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).

Comment: it's for any url, example.com is really only example

Answer (score 3):

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9./]+$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/24

Use

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?example\.[a-zA-Z0-9./]+$
```

If you want to match `example.` something.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/26

Comment: It works well but I need detect these urls in plain text (maybe I wasn't too precise in my explanation)) and replace by url token... something like this: status.replaceAll(yourRegex, "_URL_");

Answer (score 1):

This should work reasonably well to match any URL:

```
(https?://)?\w+(\.\w+)+(/\w+)*(/\w+\.\w+)?(\?[\w%&=.]*)*(?=[^\w.?&%=])
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/useSQRSfpz)

It matches any number of path parts too, eg `example.com/a/b/c?x=y&a=b

Comment: It works well but I need detect these urls in plain text (maybe I wasn't too precise in my explanation)) and replace by url token... something like this: status.replaceAll(yourRegex, "_URL_");

Comment: @petr I've modified it to work anywhere within text

Comment: please and is it possible do this for any url? example.com was only example.. Thank you!